# How to introduce Complex Where Filtering in REST

Tags: web-services, rest, soa

I'm trying to figure out:

- if this even makes sense to go this deep in a URI and
- how would I specify multi-level filtering on a resource such as below.

Example:  Person

A person has had several drivers license lets say.  And each drivers license has location information.

Person:

```
{
    "id": 222,
    "name": "Andy",
    "licenses": [
        {
            "type": 4,
            "location": {
                "country": 12,
                "city": 333,
                "state": 58
            }
        },
        {
            "type": 4,
            "location": {
                "country": 53,
                "city": 633,
                "state": 23
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Ok and lets say a consumer of our API wants to get all people whos drivers license was in country 53 (name for that country is lets say "USA").

I want to be able to call the API and somehow specify that I want this via querystring field filters.

I can't figure out how to represent filtering that goes x levels down, here being a couple levels.

I mean I started to think about it and got stuck /persons?licenses(type=drivers, location(country=53))

obviously this is just pseudo code and not even really something I'd use so how would you signify levels and filter on those levels like this?  Or is there some way to still do a lot of that in the hierarchical part of the URI?

And I don't think you can specify filtering for this in that part of the URI...because the hierarchical part is for finding a specific resource first that you want to act upon.  I don't think it's meant to be doing sublevel filtering in addition to finding a resource in the hierarchical part in this particular situation because the last resource you have in your {resource}/{id}/{resource}/{id} type of deal means the last resource is what you'll get back and that's not what I want, I don't want back the Country resource representation, I want back a list of persons in this case.

Comment: For what it’s worth, Yahoo! dealt with this problem by [inventing their own SQL-like query language](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/). They were trying to build a whole platform, though, not provide access to a single site’s data, so that might not be entirely relevant as that has a much broader scope.

Comment: but there has to be common ways people allow filtering like this in REST.  I mean everyone has to have this kinda need, business gets complex.